Why is Calvinism considered incompatible with Dispensationalism?
What amongst the five Solas and the TULIP concepts are incompatible with Dispensationalism, which I simplisticly understand to mean that the Church has not replaced the literal land and nation of Israel, and the Jews, as the object of God's pronouncements recorded in the Old Testament?
My understanding of the Bible and the Gospel would be described as Calvinism before I  discovered what Calvinism was! To me it appeared to be the only coherent set of fundamentals, anchored in God's Sovereignty, for Christianity to be internally consistent. My view of Israel flowed from my own, similarly independent conclusions as to the reliability of Scripture, and that was that God would be "dealing" with Israel (the land, the nation, the Jews) per the Old Testament. I saw no inconsistency there whatsoever. Are there fundamentals that I don't appreciate in Calvinism and Dispensationalism that make it logically or at least epistemiologically incoherent to "agree" with both?

Welcome to SE-C. PLease see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. I am personally not clear on your own definition of Dispensationalism. I think some more clarity would assist your question.

Thank you for this new question, Nigel Peters. For clarity could you say which group you attribute as having the belief that "the Church has not replaced the literal land and nation of Israel, and the Jews, as the object of God's pronouncements recorded in the Old Testament"? Do you mean the Dispensationalists, or the Reformed Protestant (Calvinistic-type) group? Or both? Thanks, in anticipation.

The inconsistencies between Dispensationalism and Calvinism primarily are in other parts of both theological systems. The word "Dispensationalism" generally means more than simply the Church/Israel distinction which you have outlined (though it does include that). Likewise, "Calvinism" refers to a school of thought including much more than simply TULIP and the five solas, though those are central to it.
Simplified Dispensationalism and Calvinism
Per your post, let's simplify each school of thought down to its core distinctives:
Dispensationalism - "The Church has not replaced the literal land and nation of Israel, and the Jews, as the object of God's pronouncements recorded in the Old Testament."
Calvinism - the Five Solas and TULIP. I'll be focusing on the five solas, which are sola scriptura, sola fida, sola gratia, solus Christus and soli Deo gloria.
There is a tension between solus Christus and Dispensationalism, though not an outright contradiction. Dividing the Church and Israel into continuing distinct covenantal communities lends itself to the idea that Jews are saved under the Mosaic and/or Abrahamic Covenants, not under the New Covenant mediated through Christ. That idea has been historically held by many Dispensationalist theologians, though it is rare today. This idea is, of course, directly contrary to solus Christus, i.e. the idea that salvation is found in Christ alone. Some ways Dispensationalists avoid this difficulty include seeing the Mosaic and Abrahamic Covenants as non-salvific in nature, or seeing some overlap between the Old and New Covenants.
More subtly, but more commonly, Dispensationalism often entails the idea that, prior to the coming of Christ, salvation was achieved by works of the Mosaic Law. This also contradicts solus Christus for the same reason, as well as sola gratia, since it means that pre-Christian salvation was not by grace alone, but by grace and works together.
It should also be noted that there is a lot of internal diversity within both schools of thought. For instance, there are Dispensationalists with Arminian soteriology who would disagree with all five points of TULIP. However, Dispensationalism as a system can accommodate the five points of Calvinism just as well.
Other Contradictions
Within the broader theological systems of Calvinism and Dispensationalism, other contradictions arise, which is why the two schools of thought are not compatible. For instance:
Most notably, an important idea within Calvinism is covenantal theology, which is essentially the converse of Dispensationalism. Covenantal theology holds that the New Covenant is the fulfillment and consummation of the Old Covenants, and that these are all part of the Covenant of Grace by which God saves sinful humans. According to Covenantal theology, the Church is the continuation of OT Israel and the inheritor of the covenant blessings thereof. (And, contrary to the claims of many Dispensationalists, this does have its roots in Scripture, not Church tradition. See my answer to this other question.)
On eschatology, Calvinism is amillennial or postmillennial, while Dispensationalism is premillennial. John Calvin once called premillennialism "too childish either to need or to be worth a refutation," (Institutes Book 3, XXV.5). Some modern Calvinist theologians are historical (post-trib) premillennialist, but this is a minority view. The Dispansationalist idea of the rapture as a distinct event from the glorious 2nd coming of Christ (pre- or mid-trib rapture) is utterly foreign to Calvinist eschatology, and Calvinists would contend that it is also foreign to Scripture.
There is also some degree of tension between Dispensationalism and the Calvinist doctrine of Perspicuity of Scripture, since Dispensationalism requires you to adopt a lot of modern (i.e., not attested by the historical church) interpretations of Scripture regarding eschatology and the relationship between the covenants. While not innately contradicting perspicuity of Scripture, it is certainly an uphill battle to claim on the one hand that the Bible teaches something clearly while on the other hand no-one noticed it until modern times.

I have not yet read all of this particular series examining Dispensational Theology as compared to the theology underlying the TULIP acronym but the following installment, "Dispensationalism and TULIP – Unconditional Election" seems to indicate that one definite incompatibility is that of "double predestination":

Most dispensationalists would feel comfortable with the following
declaration:
Before the world was made, God’s eternal, immutable purpose, which
originated in the secret counsel and good pleasure of His will, moved
Him to choose (or to elect), in Christ, certain of mankind to
everlasting glory.  Out of His mere free grace and love He
predestinated these chosen ones to life, although there was nothing in
them to cause Him to choose them.  Rom. 8:30; 9:13, 16; Eph. 1:4,
9,11; 1 Thess. 5:9; 2 Tim. 1:9. – A Faith to Confess: The Baptist
Confession of Faith of 1689, “God’s Decree,” Chapter 3. 5, (21).
They would not, however, feel quite as comfortable with this
statement:
The Reformed Faith has held to the existence of an eternal, divine
decree which, antecedently to any difference or desert in men
themselves, separates the human race into two portions and ordains one
to everlasting life and the other to everlasting death. – Loraine
Boettner, The Reformed Doctrine of Predestination, P & R, 1976, 83

A second incompatibility is discussed later as centering on the "people of God".  The Cannons of Dort, articles 8 and 9, define one and only one people of God in the Divine economy from first to last:

FIRST HEAD: ARTICLE 8. There are not various decrees of election, but one and the same decree respecting all those who shall be saved, both under the Old and New Testament; since the Scripture declares the good pleasure, purpose, and counsel of the divine will to be one, according to which He has chosen us from eternity, both to grace and to glory, to salvation and to the way of salvation, which He has ordained that we should walk therein
This article, taken with Article 9 makes it clear that Dort believed that there is just one people of God.  Acceptance of these Articles is thus implicit rejection of the Israel/Church dichotomy which is so central to DT

